# savedInstance bundle passed in two callbacks of activity

Tags: android, android-activity

When We can call onSaveInstanceState() to retrieve per-instance state from an activity before being killed so that the state can be restored in onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)

Why the Bundle populated by this method will be passed to both these callbacks? 
Is there any specific reason behind it.

Comment: This is probably a question for the Android engineers. Maybe file it here? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Answer (score 2):

> Most implementations will simply use `onCreate(Bundle)` to restore their state, but it is sometimes convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done or to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default implementation. The default implementation of this method performs a restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`.
>
> -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29#

`onRestoreInstanceState` exists for inheritance convenience.